# Yellow dots in the dope sheet that can't be edited or deleted

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I have those yellow dots with a black center in the dope sheet, and they only appear after the action, and they are related with no bones. I can't edit or delete them. I'm wondering what they are? How were they created? And how can I delete them?

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/